# Get connections Linkedin not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, linkedin-api

We used Linkedin api get connections for the team feature, then I had issue `Access to connections denied`. Can you help me resolved this issue? Quick view Application permission at pic below:

[image: Default Application Permissions]

This is full error:

```
 {
   errorCode: 0,
   message: "Access to connections denied",
   requestId: "AM5BULWZB2",
   status: 403,
   timestamp: 1434961268459,
   error: {
     code: 403,
     message: "Access to connections denied"
   }
 }
```